# SOAPUI SAVING A PDF STREAM RESPONSE IN A FILE

Tags: pdf, soapui

I'm sorry but in SOAP UI isn't so easy to save the response in a file. In POSTMAN it's actually easy.
Could you be so kind to suggest a step by step procedure ? I'm not a programmer really.
Thank you.